# Django - Javascript - Csrf Token

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, post, csrf

This is the code I have attempted to try and add a csrf token to a javascript form.

```
function save() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    console.log(form);
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', '/quiz_score/');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'Score');
    i.setAttribute('value', ""+score);
    i.setAttribute('name', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
    i.setAttribute('value', {% csrftoken %});
    form.appendChild(i);
    form.submit();
}
```

Can you see any problems with this? It has an error and therefore the JS does not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{% csrftoken %}` template tagoutputs the actual form tag (e.g. `<input type='hidden' ... />`.

If you just want the value of the token, use `{{ csrf_token }}` instead.

If you are submitting the form with an ajax request, you might find it easier to send the CSRF token as a header, rather than adding the tag to your form. [See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) for instructions.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 errors in your code. Simple way look at code.
Try it:

```js
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.setAttribute('name', 'Score');
i.setAttribute('value', ""+score);
form.appendChild(i);
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.setAttribute('name', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
i.setAttribute('value', '{{ csrf_token }}');
form.appendChild(i);
```